# Refresh main view controller after user has logged in on a different view controller

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, authentication, nsuserdefaults

I have a main view controller with a button allow a user to "Sign In"  Once they press the button it loads a different view that handles logging in.  My login view controller handles all the checks and queries my mysql database to make sure a user exists and is valid.  Once a user is valid how do I refresh my main view controller than has already been loaded so that it gathers my users information.  For example, instead of having my "Sign In" button on my main controller say 'Sign In' now I want it to say their email.  I have no problem passing this information but how do i refresh my main view controller so that it now knows a user has been logged in from a different view controller.

**LoginViewController**

```
if(resultValue == "Success"){

   UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "isLoggedIn");
   UserDefaults.standard.synchronize();

}
```

**MainViewController**

```
override func viewWillAppear() {

    super.viewWillAppear()

    let isloggedin = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "isLoggedIn")

    if (isloggedin == true){

        SignInButton.title = "Email"


    }else{

        SignInButton.title = "Sign In"
    }
}
```

Comment: fire a notification / delegate which tells the main view controller about already login info and when this screen renders then loads information based on Logged in not first time login

Comment: Hmm i see.. ill give it a shot...any examples would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In case you need to "send" info to specific recipient (MainViewController) as advised above you could use delegate or closure mechanisms (otherwise notification mechanism could be used). Please find below illustration of closure.

Note the line "lvc.action = {() in print(self)}" in that line closure ensures that the reference to self is transferred to LoginVC, so despite that the code is running in LoginVC, the print result is MainVC. Hope that helps.

Code is probably not optimal, but shows the point. It is complete illustration for (Xcode 8.1 (8B62)): Delete storyboard, launchscreen, Clean properties Main story board and Launchscreen in Info.plist and replace AppDelegate.swift with the following content

```
import UIKit

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
    var window: UIWindow?
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
        self.window!.rootViewController = MainViewController()
        self.window!.makeKeyAndVisible()
        return true
    }
}

class LoginViewController: UIViewController {
    var action: (()->())!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let b = self.view.addSubviewWithConstraints(["b" : Button(title: "Validate user")], constraints: ["V:|-10-[b(70)]", "H:|-10-[b]-10-|"])["b"]
        (b as! Button).action = self.action

    }
}

class MainViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let b = self.view.addSubviewWithConstraints(["b" : Button(title: "Log in")], constraints: ["V:|-10-[b(70)]", "H:|-10-[b]-10-|"])["b"]
        (b as! Button).action = {
            let lvc = LoginViewController()
            lvc.action = {() in print(self)}
            self.present(lvc, animated: false,completion: nil)
        }
    }
}

class Button: UIButton {
    var action: (()->())!
    init(title: String) {
        super.init(frame : CGRect.zero)
        self.setTitle(title, for: UIControlState())
        self.addTarget(self, action: #selector(Button.buttonAction(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    }
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {super.init(coder: coder)}
    func buttonAction(_ sender: AnyObject) {if action != nil {action()}}
}

extension UIView {
    func addSubviewWithConstraints(_ views: [String : AnyObject], constraints: Array<String>) -> [String : AnyObject] {
        for (_, view) in views {
            self.addSubview(view as! UIView)
            (view as! UIView).translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        }
        for i in 0 ..< constraints.count {self.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: constraints[i], options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(rawValue: 0), metrics: nil, views: views))}
        return views
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer.  I will test it out.  These seems insanely overly complicated compared to PHP just starting a session.  I have to believe there is a better way than this.  There has to be something to share user data from one view to another based off a simple bool to check if user is logged in or not.  I can't possibly imagine that this is the easiest solution.